# CUPS-PDF Help figuring out which configuration file is being used

Tags: printing, pdf, cups-lpd

I cannot seem to figure out which configuration file is being used.
My printer keeps working. This is a remote setup, I don't have the admin interface setup.

I have just done a batch find on my printer server for `.ppd` files and listed them all out like this:

```
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/cbjc800-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/cbjc600-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/ghostpdf-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF_opt-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF_noopt-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/HP-Color_LaserJet_CM3530_MFP-PDF-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/pxlcolor.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/Generic-PDF_Printer-PDF-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/Fuji_Xerox-DocuPrint_CM305_df-PDF.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/Ricoh-PDF_Printer-PDF-tmp.ppd
/usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/pxlmono.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/PDF-tmp.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/john4-tmp.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/john-tmp.ppd
```

Notice the `tmp` that's me trying to purposely destroy this printer so I can tell which one it's using. The end goal is I'm trying to guarantee the page size and margins are set correctly since the printed documents are chopped at the margins. I've set `etc/pagesize`, I've set the `*Order`... anyway the point is I don't know which file actually matters.

The logs for some reason are not showing much info. CUPS-PDF in my case was installed with Ubuntu it's not from source, I have tried to compile that myself but couldn't get it to work granted I was not on a RHEL platform.

I am restarting every time (cups service), even restarted the server, still the printer works/no change in behavior.

Printer says it's using:

```
Driver: Generic CUPS-PDF Printer (no options) (color)
Connection: cups-pdf:/
```

Comment: well this is not going well, I've tried updating the cups-pdf.conf file, it should be using one of the ppd above (noopt). I tried using lpoptions to set page-top/PageTop to 0, nothing... cannot change the end result PDF... going to try Debian, then worst case open-suse/RHEL something that is closer to what cups-pdf.de says regarding compiling. Part of the issue I'm still looking into is the separate configs per user and that is supposed to work. This is one of those things just pay someone to do it, I don't want to learn about how a printer works from scratch eg. writing my own GhostScript

Comment: I did at least realize that the /lsb/... paths when you do a find for --make-and-model with lpinfo are "copies" of the paths in /usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/... so I'm thinking/hoping I gotta change this file before I use it to make a new printer, and then the changes should be inheritted/what ends up in /etc/cups/ppd/printer.ppd